# Request to reopen this interesting question

Tags: support, close-reasons, closed-questions

This following question was marked as duplicate by mistake(as it seems to me).

- [Move running program to background in bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186322/move-running-program-to-background-in-bash)

Marked Duplicate:

- [Running programs in the background from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal)

The pointed out duplicate, answers various ways to send a program to background. But what the OP of the new question has asked, is a way to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and the `bg` option together so as to move a process to background and continue its running state in one go. So, I request to reopen this interesting and yet un-answered question.

Comment: oru vote koodi kittiyal athu reopen cheyyam

Comment: @tachyons, Wouldn't have guessed that you're a Malayali if not for that comment. :) Good to see more Malayalees here. Cheers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Done, it is now reopened

please check revision history for details